# How do I Convert a Ttf or other Font to a .Xnb/XNA Game Studio Font?

Tags: fonts, xna, xna-4.0, truetype

I'm working with a game Called Terraria on a complete texture redo. The Font is PNG based, which I extracted from the Font XNBs using TConvert. Is there a fast method of making a font convert to something like Font1.ttf > Font1.xnb.

I already tried:

XNA Game studio and using Re-Logics Font Pipeline to make a custom font, but due to the Overall Outdated-ness of XNA game studio 4.0, I can not install it. It requires Visual C# 2010 which does NOT work with my Windows 7 PC. (I'm not completely sure why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MonoGame to create an `.xnb` file for use with Terraria.

A version of steps 6-10 with screenshots can be found [here](http://community.monogame.net/t/no-spritefont-template-workaround/2576/2).

1. Install the font file in Windows. Open the `ttf` file and click install(Note the name).
2. If you do not already have it, install a [community version of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/).
3. Install [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/).
4. Create a new Windows Game from the provided MonoGame Template.(Note the project directory)
5. Open the MonoGame Pipeline Tool by double-clicking on the Content.mgcb file.
6. From the Edit Menu, Select Add -> New Item
7. Name the file and select SpriteFont Description.
8. Right click on the file under Content, select Open With.
9. Edit the file using a text editor(Notepad). Change the font name and size. Save the file.
10. Select Build -> Rebuild from the Menu.
11. The `.xnb` file is in: *project directory*/bin/x86/Debug/Content/

The most common error is the name of the font is not correct.

Comment: Thankyou, I cant try this at the moment but at least now I have a option that DOESN'T require XNA Game Studio.